# Related VieWController should show Label from Cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uilabel

I try to show the Label from a Cell in a new ViewController when you tap on the cell, so it should be a function like in twitter
I tried following code, but the label just don't show the message from the cell, its just blank...

```
var jobs = [Job]()
let jobsRef = Database.database().reference().child("jobs")

var job: Job! {
    didSet {
        jobLabel.text = job.text
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // download jobs
    jobsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.jobs.removeAll()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
            let job = Job(snapshot: childSnapshot)
            print(job)
            self.jobs.insert(job, at: 0)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use `jobsRef`

Comment: take a look at the edited version @SteveO'Connor

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
self.jobs.removeAll()
ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                return
            }
let Obj = Job()

self.jobs.append(Obj)
self. tableView.reloadData()
}, withCancel: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

Every UIViewController that will appear within the PagerTabStrip needs to provide either a title or an image. [Discord](https://discord.software/) In order to do so they should conform to Indicator InfoProvider [Adobe Reader](https://adobereader.onl/) by implementing func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo which provides the information required to show the PagerTabStrip menu (indicator) associated with the view controller [iTunes](https://itunes.red/).